# Use iTunes on iPhone

Tags: iphone

How can we create an application from which we can access iTunes on our iPhone/iPad.

I don't want any code but if you have any suggestions than please reply.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's already built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the AddMusic Sample App from Apple

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html